Magento 2 Product Save Issue
When I have save product it's throw below error from magento.
Warning: Array to string conversion in vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/CacheContext.php on line 73

I have many product attributes in my Magento store, and I suspect this might be causing the issue. However, this error only occurs for certain products, so I'm unable to pinpoint the exact cause.
Can anyone help me find a solution for this issue?

here are not enough details; at the very least, the logs need to be reviewed.
